# Permitir múltiples elementos en un Drag n' Drop

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Lo que quiero hacer es que un componente tipo contenedor acepte más de un elemento "draggable", es decir, que a un div le pueda arrastrar y soltar varios elementos y estos queden almacenados dentro de él y se queden como "hijos" del div.

HTML:

```
<div class="contenedorConceptosFactura">
<table class="table">
    @*Encabezados de la tabla de contenido*@
    <tr>
        <th>
            No. Identificación
        </th>
        <th>
            Descripción
        </th>
        <th>
            Cantidad
        </th>
        <th>
            Recepciones
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model.modelo)
    {

            //Cada uno de los registros de la tabla
            <tr id="@contadorIdConceptosFactura">
                <td id="@noIdent">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.noIdent)
                </td>
                <td id="@descripcion">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.descripcion)
                </td>
                <td id="@cantidad">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.cantidad)
                </td>
                // Contenedor para soltar elementos, pero solo me permite soltar uno
                <td id="@contenedorRecibo" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" class="contenedorConceptosReciboEnFactura"></td>

                <td id="@valorUnitario" style="display: none;">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.valorUnitario)
                </td>

            </tr>
            // Variable que funcionará para el ID de cada registro
            contadorIdConceptosFactura++;
    }
</table>
```

JS:

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
ev.preventDefault();
}


function drag(ev) {
ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}


function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    var x = document.getElementById(ev.target.id).hasChildNodes();

    if (x) {
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    } 
}
```

Hasta el momento, solo me permite "soltar" un elemento en el contenedor con ID 'contenedorRecibo' y lo que me gustaría es que pudiera dejar más de uno

Comment: Saludos, es mejor si agregas tu código lo que has intentando  para poder darte una mejor respuesta, en tanto investiga esto: https://jqueryui.com/draggable

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29211312/how-to-drag-and-drop-a-div-inside-another-div-and-make-that-the-whole-element-fo

Comment: Prueba esto: [Arrastrar y soltar](http://w3.unpocodetodo.info/jsblog/arrastrar-y-soltar.php).